Regarding manually entering key for secure boot
Currently I enabled secure boot in my desktop with Ubuntu22.04.
During NVIDIA driver installation it asks for secure boot password which should be manually entered  on reboot of the desktop so that the NVIDIA graphics card is UP with the installed driver.
Since I am planning to place this desktop in a remote location and I really don't want to disable secure boot, how can I take care of manually entering the key on every reboot of the desktop without driving down to remote location?

In your situation, you should use the ubuntu-drivers tool to install the Nvidia drivers, so that the kernel modules are pre-signed by Canonical (rather than locally signed as part of installation). This completely avoids that Machine Owner Key (MOK) enrollment process when rebooting.
More detail about the ubuntu-drivers tool: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation
And for what it's worth, the password prompt you saw there is in order to add a locally-generated signature for the installed kernel+Nvidia modules combination to your UEFI setup (the "DKMS" path). If you take that approach, entering the Secure Boot/MOK password is only required when rebooting after installing and compiling the newly signed kernel modules, not after every reboot of the machine.

Thanks for the reply. So the password is only needed one time i.e. when I install the new NVIDIA driver and reboot the desktop. Once rebooted any future reboots would not need manually providing the password. Let me try the same.

It worked. Well i ended up installing CUDA 12 version from NVIDIA and provided password during reboot. On further reboot as you suggested I dont need to enter any passwords. I will try ubuntu-drivers approach in future.
